# C program, where I should print array of a SECTION in an array

Tags: c

I built a program in C that is printing average of whole array with pointers and function. I need to make the function print a average of user selected section of an array, for example I put these number in an array: 9,8,2,3,6,4 and I want to make a average from just 2-4-. I am stucked, can you help me please? Thanks.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int priemer(int *pole,int n);

int main()
{
    int a[100],*pole,n,i;
    printf("Zadaj pocet prvkov pola (1-100)");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while (n > 100 || n < 1)
    {
        printf("Chyba! Cislo musi byt v rozmedzi od 1 po 100.\n");
        printf("Zadaj pocet prvkov znova: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Zadaj %d. prvok - ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    pole=a;
    priemer(pole,n);
    return 0;
}

int priemer(int *pole,int n)
{
    int i,c=0;
    float p;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        c+=*(pole+i);
    }
    p=(float)c/n;
    printf("Priemer vsetkych prvkov v poli je: %.3f\n",p);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: "I am stucked". Where? What fails? What still works? What are the symptoms?

Comment: If you would translate everything the shown code would be more self-explanatory.

Comment: Try `for(i=a;i<b;i++)` with `a` and `b` provided by the user?

Comment: I did it like for(i=a;i<b;i++) in function but its giving me wrong results. I put 3 elements (1,2,3) and I selected a = 2, b = 3 and it threw me average: 1,333

Comment: a and b are supposed to be indices right?

Comment: yes they are :))

Comment: Are you sure about your average? I don't get 1.333 with those numbers.